# Is the "Reddick, Boseman & Kolstad" law firm at the same location as the former "Stern, Lockhart, & Gardner"?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-good-fight

Much of the television series *The Good Wife* took place at the law firm, "Stern, Lockhart, & Gardner" (and "Lockhart & Gardner", "Lockhart, Gardner, & Bond", etc) a law firm existing somewhere in Chicago that featured the 27th and 28th floors of the same building through every season, despite the ongoing "partner" change-up.

Similarly, in the spin-off series *The Good Fight* much of the series takes place at the law firm, "Reddick, Boseman & Kolstad"  ( and "Reddick, Boseman, Lockhart", etc).

(*The Good Fight - Left, The Good Wife - Right*)
[image: Good]

I noticed however that Diane's corner office from the *The Good Wife* is the same as Adrian Boseman's corner office in *The Good Fight*, at least in terms of size and "exterior" window and city scape, as both offices have ornate stone work and some kind of "flame" statue at the [viewer's] right corner!

(*Diane Lockhart's Office 1.01 The Good Fight*)
[image: Diane's Office TGF]

But oddly, at the end of *The Good Wife*, Diane was interested in buying out the 29th floor of the same building after a remolding mishap, but clearly during the pilot of *The Good Fight*, one can see the law firm she is about to retire from takes place in totally different building, as her office too is different, but due to Rindell Scandal, Diane can't retire and is offered a job to work for Boseman at his law firm.

However the reality that Diane is going back to the same building and floor she occupied and was the boss of during most of the predecessor series is, to my knowledge, never addressed on the series!

So my question is, ***is it mean to be the same building "in-universe" or did the Kings just reuse the same office space/sets in hopes viewers wouldn't notice?***

Comment: Both shows are filmed at the same soundstage in Brooklyn -- https://www.thecinemaholic.com/where-is-the-good-fight-filmed/ -- so they'll likely reuse sets from TGW for TGF.

Comment: @BCdotWEB I do imagine they reuse sets/locations, as I have also seen two fronts of the same building in The Good Fight and Evil for two small scenes. However, my concern here is that TGW and TGF take place in same universe where the firm itself is like it's own character, and considering they CGI-ed colorful lights and a winged gargle statue in replacing the flame for the exterior decor in season 4 (ie: theme: Belly of the Beast), this is something that would be seriously noticed by long-time fans and I would of CGI-ed the stonework out...